# How to install KivEnt on Ubuntu?

Tags: games, python3, python-2.7, kivy

I'm currently learning Kivy for making some simple games as my project work. I recently found out that there is something called as KivEnt that can make Game developement on Kivy more reliable. But I couldn't find any good tutorials or guide on installing the KivEnt. So if there anyone who knows how to install KivEnt(Including Chipmunk 2d and Cymunk), Please give me a detailed guide on it.

- Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

you have to install kivy first:

```
pip3 install kivy
```

then install kivent_core from this repo(https://github.com/kivy/kivent.git):

```
cd .../KivEnt/modules/core
python3 setup.py build_ext install
```

then install cymunk from this repo(https://github.com/kivy/cymunk.git):

```
python3 setup.py build_ext install
```

then install kivent_cymunk using the same repo for kivent_core(https://github.com/kivy/kivent.git):

```
cd .../KivEnt/modules/cymunk
python3 setup.py build_ext install
```

This is how it worked with me!